# How to update the date saved in database when system time is changed using java

Tags: java, mysql, date, time

My requirement is.

First i will log in to my application .After log in i need to check weather this person already logged in today or not.If that person is logging first time today then i need to call a web service other wise there is no need to call a web service.

I did as follows..

I created a table which contains the date field , i am saving the date in that field when ever user logged in. In user is going to log in again after some time(same day) i am checking in the database for date.This is working fine for me.

### Problem

If the user changes the system date what i need to do?.How i can update the date in database automatically in database.are there any other possibilities?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: In sql server we have GETDATE() function,so even if you change then local system time it will not effect because getdate() will be executed in server.So it will take servers time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user changes his system date is not your business.
When the user log in, you save the date into your table, this date must be your database system date.
I believe the user can't change your database system date, right? So you don't need to worry about it.